# OGC spec in OpenAPI fomat

Tags: wms, api, ogc, ogc-api

Is there any description of OGC WMS specification in OpenAPI / Swagger format ?

I found an [initiative](http://www.opengeospatial.org/projects/initiatives/wfs3hackathon) for WFS protocol, but nothing on WMS.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to myself : I found some implementation on this github repository : https://github.com/smartcommunitylab/sco.geoserver/blob/master/swaggerGeoServerWMS.yaml

Comment: This is unofficial, and has at least one error ~ for example,  neither layers or styles are required if the layer name is supplied as part of  SLD or SLD_BODY.  authkey is not required

Comment: I agree but at least this is a starting point